# In the Windows Command Prompt, why is there a large amount of empty space below the prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

I've been using Command Prompt in Windows for a while now and only just realized that there are several pages worth of empty lines below the prompt. Why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The "large amount of empty space" is the rows of the screen buffer that have not yet been filled with output.

To change the screen buffer from the default of 300 lines, perform the following steps:

1. Open command prompt.
2. Right click the application icon (in the upper left corner)
3. Click on Properties
4. Select the Layout tab
5. Set the Screen Buffer Size, Height to 20.
6. Click OK

**Note:** I recommend reverting the buffer size as 20 lines isn't many lines of displayed output.

Comment: The screen buffer is the number of rows and columns of command prompt output saved in memory.  The window size is how much of the buffer is displayed in the window.

Comment: @Jay The area outside the bounds of the currently displayed `cmd` window that can be viewed using the vertical scroll bar. It is usually used to view previous commands and output that are no longer visible.

Comment: Instead of changing it back to the default I recommend to change it to the maximum supported value of 9999 lines. That's no really an issue memory-allocation-wise on computers that have been manufactured in this century and it can be quite helpful when running scripts that produce a lot of output.

Comment: @Kaiserludi Tell that to my 2007 Macbook running a massive rails app ;)

Comment: @zpr we can still run into memory issues, but they likely won't be caused by the screen buffer in `cmd`.

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* though. *Why* does the Windows command window allow the user to scroll to space that hasn't been written to yet? Compare to the Mac OS X Terminal and most Linux terminals, which allow a maximum buffer size but don't allow the user to scroll to areas that haven't been used yet.

Comment: Also compare to older versions of Windows, which also did not allow the user to scroll to space that hadn't been written to yet. (At least that's how I remember it working in WinXP and prior.)

Answer (score 11):

I know this is not the why, that has been covered by @steven.  If you want to change the screen buffer from within a command prompt or batch file you can make use of the `mode` command (mode columns, lines). I regularly use this from within the command prompt:

```
mode 200, 300
```

Comment: That's a cool function! I never seen that before!

Comment: MODE is as old as they get. In DOS, the MODE command allowed you to switch between different character modes supported by the graphics adapter hardware. The choices were very limited. On the IBM PC, the MDA had no options (always 80x25) and CGA had just two (MODE 80 and MODE 40). More advanced adapters later introduced more options, including more than 25 lines. VGA for example had MODE 80,43 which used the shorter CGA character matrix on a denser VGA resolution (350 scan lines instead of 200) to provide an extra 18 lines of text. I think the "height" parameter was added maybe on DOS 3.3?

Comment: This is a bit of a necro, but @EuroMicelli tripped my nostalga so I thought I'd point out a completely unrelated use for the command.  I had "MODE CON: rate=32 delay=1" in the autoexec.bat for every DOS install setup.  Still works today in the console, but it's the default, so no need.

Comment: @alzee, oh yes absolutely, same here. The default BIOS repeat rate and delay are junk. Those settings, now via the Windows’ Keyboard Control Panel, is just about the first thing I check on a new system.